# ASP NET SQL - select * from where author

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net, vb.net

I'm having a problem showing equal results from SQL database

```
"select * from Log where Author=" + User.Identity.Name
```

That's the current command I've tried, but can't get it working.

while this works:

```
"select * from Log where Author='markus'"
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You need quotes around the value User.Identity.Name in the SQL statement.

Comment: "select * from Log where Author='" + User.Identity.Name + "'"

Comment: I dont recommend doing this but try wrapping the string into single quotes: `"select * from Log where Author='" + User.Identity.Name + "'"`. Standard way of doing this is using prepared statements.

Comment: oh, ofcourse, thanks @SloanThrasher

Comment: @GurV - what do you mean with prepared statements? I'm new to SQL

Comment: @Luke - Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements

Comment: @GurV - Thanks alot, I'll take a look at it!

Comment: @LukeRemming You've heard of SQL injection, right? You don't want to be that useless coder who let it happen. This is what you are allowing with code like this. NEVER glue strings together to form sql statements unless you're 100% sure about the origin of those strings. You can write secure code very easily with [parameterized queries](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/268104-the-right-way-to-query-a-database-parameterizing-your-sql-queries/). You'd be a fool not to. Really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the string in single quotes like this:

```
"select * from Log where Author='" + User.Identity.Name + "'"
```

However the standard way of doing this is using parameterized statements:

```
"select * from Log where Author = @Author";
```

Then apply the value to param `@Author` using `SqlParameter`.

For more info, see:

- [Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements)

Comment: DON'T DO THIS. @GurV : You should preface you answer with "This is how ***not*** to do what you want", or bring the risk of SQL injection to the forefront. People looking for quick answers won't bother following a link when they see how easily your solution "works".

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
"Select * from Log where Author='" + User.Identity.Name + "'"
```

Actually your query is missing single quotes for name that is a string..

Comment: Say my username is `';drop table users;`?

Comment: @spender Actually `'; drop table Log; --` would be worse.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use string.Format method for this kind of situations.
Try the following.

```
string query=string.Format("select * from Log where Author='{0}'",User.Identity.Name)
```